# How to copy single file using robocopy?

Tags: robocopy

I'm trying to copy a single file to the "Computer Backups" folder as shown below.  The command does not work, even thought the syntax is correct, i.e., "source dest file".  I've tried many permutations of this command, different quoting, and still it does not work. I've also tried running it using admin privs, to no avail.  My  guess is that it is a quoting issue.

```
robocopy F:\ "C:\Users\ben\OneDrive\Computer Backups" "HP Pavillion to USB_full_b2_s1_v1.tib"
```

-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, the problem was that OneDrive has a file size limit, and this file is 221 GB.